# "Camera Busy" dialog shows on Moto X 2013 when I launch camera app

Tags: camera, moto-x

I have a problem my Moto x 2013 camera says it is busy every time I start the  Motorola camera app. Third party apps also have trouble using the camera. My phone is  on Android version 5.1 but it has been happening when my phone was on 4.4.4.

I have restarted my phone, rebooted it in safe mode, factory reset my Moto x and my camera still says  "Camera Busy". I also cleared my Moto x cache partition but it did not work.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: Attached screenshot of the problem]

Comment: See ["Can't connect to camera", Nexus 6 - Lollipop 5.1](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/117070)